# Should I make interfaces for my entities?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Is it normal/recommended to make interfaces for the entities in an application? If it is should getter/setters be declared in the interface or only business methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface are for business logic, It's declare the behavior or functionality of your module.
POJO's are just objects that contains data and not suppose to do any logic- so not.

Comment: The OO-Paradigma tell's us that we should put the data and it's functionaltity into one class. Splitting this may be usefull for technical reasons but violates OO .

Comment: When we talk on PlainOldJavaObject we talk about objects that contains only data (properties) with no logic- only getters and setters. you're right about objects with functionality (that probably contains data)- and it's should not be split.

Comment: >The OO-Paradigma tell's us that we should put the data and it's functionaltity into one class. - Does a cake bake itself? Does `cake.bake()` makes any sense???

Comment: Yes, that's why java has static methods.

Comment: @BetaRide or just methods in Services, DAOs and backing beans ;) There is no need for static methods. The service can still have state, like references to other beans, data sources etc.

Comment: POJOs are not just objects that contain data. In fact, one of the coiner of the term POJO, Martin Fowler, would classify your description under anaemic domain model, which he considers an anti-pattern. Therefore, this is not just wrong; it's misleading by repurposing POJO, which Fowler advocates, to an anti-pattern.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Of course, if you are giving a silly example, it won't make sense. `cake.bake()` doesn't make sense, but `cake.isEdible()` surely makes sense which would be determined based on its ingredient or expiration date, some of which might not need to be exposed beyond encapsulation.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Of course, if you are giving a silly example, it won't make sense. `cake.bake()` doesn't make sense, but `cake.isEdible()` surely makes sense which would be determined based on its ingredient or expiration date, some of which might not need to be exposed beyond encapsulation.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP
The question is, is Martin Fowler always right about everything? I would rather call it a "slim domain model" as opposed to a "fat domain model". `Cake.isEdible()` would be fine if it only uses simple logic with data that's directly in the entity. But 'cake.bake()` is unfortunately not just a silly example, it's something people actually tend to do in the name of "being true to OO".

Answer (score 2):

You can create interfaces if it makes sense to do so: will there be multiple classes that share the same functionality (i.e., will they expose the same interface)? In that case you can create an interface with those (business logic) methods in it.

Also, an interface does not contain variables to keep track of a state, those will be part of the class that implements the interface. Several classes with the same interface might implement it in a different way so there's no need to specify variables (and thus, getters and setters) in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interface definately shouldn't contain getters and setters. Interface provides only functionality that your class can perform (if you need getters/setters - use abstract classes). Fields usually (not always, of course) only part of implementation.

So, if your class contains only data, there is no need in interfaces

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that using an interface for an entity can be used to decouple clients from the fact that they are dealing with JPA. I sometimes have the situation that I need several derived non-persistent business objects next to persisted entities which both share the same Interface. In such cases I find this appropriate. But you should limit such uses to read only cases when you don't have to mind transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at this excellent article discussing about the "overuse" of the interface/implementation pattern. Usually entity beans are not following that kind of pattern and you will find here a good reason:

http://marekdec.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/explicit-interface-per-class-antipattern/

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont think entity/pojo as interface makes any sense, because entity or pojo has properties with getters and setters And used for data. suppose if you provide interface and its implementation(in POJO which implements interface), and you are persisting it into database using interface reference to Implementation class. It's ok it will get persisted, but what if you provide another pojo which implements same interface. It will definately violate the meaning of pojo and ofcourse it is confusing which pojo to persist.